# Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null with array

Tags: javascript

Could somebody tell what is wrong here? I have a form with validation of email address and what is supposed to do is when is correct to make a new array and to print below form and when it's not just one simple alert. This is HTML:

```
    <form>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Your email address</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="txtEmail">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" value="Register me" onclick="check();">
                </td>
            </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
```

This is JS:

```
function check() {
    var email = document.getElementById("txtEmail").value;
    var reEmail = /^(\w)+(\d)*(\.\_)*@[a-z]{2,10}\.[a-z]{2,5}$/;
    var correct = new Array();
    if(email.match(reEmail)){
        correct.push(email);
        document.getElementById("prikaz").innerHTML = correct;          
        }
        else {
            alert("Not correct");
        }

}
```

Comment: There's no `#prikaz` where to set `innerHTML` in your code.

Comment: What does this code output? Does anything happen? Did you try debugging it?

Comment: Just: TypeError: document.getElementById("prikaz") is null. I just forgot it to copy paste that div in question

Comment: Your code [seems to work](http://jsfiddle.net/6gddknvs/), if the element with the `id` of `prikaz` has been added. The email validation doesn't work correctly though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your HTML should be like this:

```
<form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Your email address</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="txtEmail">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="button" value="Register me" onclick="check();">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

  </table>

</form>
<div id="prikaz">
</div>
```

And your JS should be like this:

```
var correct =new Array();
function check() {
    var email = document.getElementById("txtEmail").value;
    var reEmail = /^(\w)+(\d)*(\.\_)*@[a-z]{2,10}\.[a-z]{2,5}$/;
    if(email.match(reEmail)){
        correct.push(email);
    }
    else {
        alert("Not correct");
    }
    var correctEmails = "<table>";
    for(var i=0; i< correct.length; i++){
        correctEmails+=("<tr><td>"+correct[i]+"</td></tr>");

    }
    correctEmails+="</table>"
    document.getElementById("prikaz").innerHTML = correctEmails; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no element with the id "prikaz" so getElementById is returning null.

And even if it did return something, I don't see the point of setting it's innerHTML to an array since that field is for text that will be parsed as HTML.

Comment: In that case array's `toString()` method is used, and the actual content of an array is shown.